# whitespace automatically added python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running this code to print a triangle pattern but I can't seem to understand why two extra whitespaces are added in between.

```
n=int(input("enter length"))
for x,s in zip(range(0,n),reversed(range(n))):
     print(s*" ","*",((x-1)*2)*"f",(x!=0)*"*")
```

the output of program is

```
    *  
   *dd*
  *dffd*
 *dffffd*
*dffffffd*
```

the extra white spaces are denoted by letter 'd'.

Comment: print adds whitespaces between its arguments by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` automatically adds spaces between its parameters:

```
>>> print(1, 2, 3)
1 2 3
>>> print("a", "b", "c")
a b c
```

You can concatenate the strings manually to solve this problem:

```
print(s*" " + "*" + ((x - 1)*2)*"f" + (x != 0)*"*")
```

or use `sep`:

```
print(s*" ", "*", ((x-1)*2)*"f", (x!=0)*"*", sep="")
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`.

Note that argument `sep` defaults to a single space.

Answer (score 3):

`print` outputs each argument with a space as the default separator. You should use the `sep=''` parameter if you want no space in between the output of the arguments:

```
print(s*" ","*",((x-1)*2)*"f",(x!=0)*"*", sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the default separator between items.
You can customize it with the `sep` keyword argument:

```
print(1,2,3,4, sep="-")
#1-2-3-4
print(1,2,3,4, sep="")
#1234
```